# SQL to combine data for single row per object

Tags: sql-server

I know this must be a common problem, but I'm not sure where to go. This occurs a few times inside a big nasty query, so here is the problem simplified. I just want one row per object, but the null on ColorOther gives me two rows.

I can think of a few things to try wrapping a query around this, but there must be something simpler... I'm off to read up on pivots.

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Colors](
[ColorId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ColoredObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ColorCode] [int] NOT NULL,
[ColorOther] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Colors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ColorId] ASC)
```

Source data

```
ColorId     ColoredObjectId ColorCode   ColorOther
----------- --------------- ----------- ----------
1           1               1           NULL
2           1               2           NULL
3           1               4           purple
4           2               2           NULL
5           2               3           NULL
6           2               4           orange
7           3               1           NULL
8           3               3           NULL
9           3               4           green
```

Query

```
SELECT   ColoredObjectId                                         ,
         ColorOther                                              ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yellow,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Red   ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blue  ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Other
FROM     Colors
GROUP BY ColoredObjectId,
         ColorOther
```

Output

```
ColoredObjectId ColorOther Yellow      Red         Blue        Other
--------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1               NULL       1           1           0           0
1               purple     0           0           0           1
2               NULL       0           1           1           0
2               orange     0           0           0           1
3               NULL       1           0           1           0
3               green      0           0           0           1
```

Desired output

```
ColoredObjectId ColorOther Yellow      Red         Blue        Other
--------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1               purple     1           1           0           1
2               orange     0           1           1           1
3               green      1           0           1           1
```

Comment: It looks like its not only the ColorOther NULL that is giving you two rows, the Other column has different values for your aggregation, so they are two different set of rows. What is the desired output for your query?, and what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What do NULL ColorOther values really mean?   Are the legitimate rows you want to see?

Comment: Just remove `ColorOther` from the `group by`

Comment: @Sparky, yes, added clarification to the question.

Comment: @Lamak, yes the null is the problem. The user can select any combination of colors and each selection has a row. The desired output is one row per object. SQL-Server 2005.

Comment: @Leslie, You would need to use `MAX(ColorOther)` in the select

Comment: @Martin - yes, please add as an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should return the desired output.

```
SELECT   ColoredObjectId                                         ,
         MAX(ColorOther) AS ColorOther                           ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yellow,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Red   ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blue  ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Other
FROM     Colors
GROUP BY ColoredObjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I am not at a SQL box, so I can't test it, but it should be pretty close)

```
SELECT   cc.ColoredObjectId                                         ,
         xx.ColorOther                                              ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yellow,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Red   ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blue  ,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ColorCode = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Other
FROM     Colors cc
JOIN     (select distinct ColorObjectID,ColorOther FROM colors 
          where colorOther is not null) xx on xx.colorObjectId=cc.colorobjectID
GROUP BY cc.ColoredObjectId,
         xx.ColorOther
```

Comment: thanks for your effort on this. It does work but there was a better solution.

Comment: I agree, I saw Martin's solution just after I posted it, much simpler and cleaner...   Good luck